# Given an array of N integers how to find the largest element which appears an even number of times in the array with minimum time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

You are given an array of N integers. You are asked to find the largest element which appears an even number of times in the array. What is the time complexity of your algorithm? Can you do this without sorting the entire array?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in `O(n log n)` with a table lookup method. For each element in the list, look it up in the table. If it is missing, insert a key-value pair with the key being the element and the value as the number of appearances (starting at one); if it is present, increment the appearances. At the end just loop through the table in O(n) and look for the largest key with an even value.

In *theory* for an ideal *hash-table*, a lookup operation is O(1). So you can find and/or insert all `n` elements in O(n) time, making the total complexity **O(n)**. However, in practice you will have trouble with space allocation (need *much* more space than data set size) and collisions (*why* you need it). This makes the O(1) lookup very difficult to achieve; in the worst case scenario it can be as much as O(n) (though also unlikely) - making the total complexity O(n^2).

Instead you can be more secure with a *tree-based* table - that is, the keys are stored in a binary tree. Lookup and insertion operations are all O(log n) in this case, provided that the tree is balanced; there are a wide range of tree structures to help ensure this e.g. Red-Black trees, AVL, splay, B-trees etc (Google is your friend). This will make the total complexity a *guaranteed* **O(n log n)**.

Comment: It might be best to say that the *expected* runtime of the hash table implementation is O(n) with a *worst-case* runtime of O(n^2) to clarify that it's extremely likely to be fast in practice, though it has an unlikely but bad worst-case.

Comment: @templatetypedef yes.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the range is small enough, you only need 1.58 bits per value {notfound, even, odd} to do it in guaranteed O(n). That's... 5 values per byte without loss.

Comment: @MooingDuck #I♥math

Comment: I don't think splay trees have a guaranteed O(log n), I think they're worst case O(n). I've never heard of a _beam_ tree, and I can't find anything on Google.

Comment: @MooingDuck sorry I meant B-trees (the ones on HDD's and so on). according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree, worst cases for search and insert are both log n

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah The bar at the top refers to expected complexity, in the same way a hashmap is O(1).  Quoting your link: "The worst-case height—though unlikely—is O(n), with the average being O(log n)." and "The most significant disadvantage of splay trees is that the height of a splay tree can be linear... Since the height of a tree corresponds to the worst-case access time, this means that the actual cost of an operation can be high. "